# Clear URL cached

Tags: json, swift, url, caching

I have a code below which works fine except pull to refresh. It returns cached version of .json. If I use different URL function it reloads new .json on the fly, but if I want to perform pull to refresh with same URL it serving cached version of it.

Thank you

```
static func loadDataFromURL(url: URL,completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = true
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
    sessionConfig.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    // Use URLSession to get data from an NSURL
    let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error!)
            if kDebugLog { print("API ERROR: \(error!)") }
            return
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            if kDebugLog { print("API: HTTP status code has unexpected value") }
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            if kDebugLog { print("API: No data received") }
            return
        }

        // Success, return data
        completion(data, nil)
    }

    loadDataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the session.configuration with a URLSessionConfiguration object which config with the cache policy according to your need which I think you haven't set on above code.

Comment: You thinking about NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData? I did try but it didn't help.

Comment: Also, please try with .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData too

Comment: I did try this but the same thing.


let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        sessionConfig.urlCache = nil
        sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy(rawValue: 1)!
        sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = true
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
        sessionConfig.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1